# Quando devo usar Herança, Classe Abstrata, Interface ou um Trait?

Tags: php, interface, herança, classes-abstratas, trait

A partir do PHP 5.4 temos o `Trait`, que "são mecanismos que ajudam (e muito) a reutilização de código, e servem perfeitamente para resolver o problema da falta de herança múltipla".

## Exemplo de Classe Abastrata

```
abstract class AbstractUser
{
    abstract public function getLanguage();
}


class PtUser extends AbstractUser
{
    public function getLanguage()
    {
        return 'pt_br';
    }
}
```

## Exemplo com Traits e Interfaces

```
class PtUser implements UserLang
{
    use TraitUserLang;
}

interface UserLang
{
    public function getLanguage();
}

trait TraitUserLang
{
    public function getLanguage()
    {
        return 'pt_br';
    }

}
```

Para os dois casos, eu poderia fazer algo como :

```
$user = new PtUser;

// caso 1
if ($user instanceof AbstractUser) {
    $user->getLanguage();
}
// caso 2
if ($user instanceof UserLang) {
      $user->getLanguage();
}
```

Aí surgiu algumas confusões na minha mente:

- Quando é que devo utilizar uma classe abstrata, ou uma simples herança?
- Quando é que devo utilizar o trait, seguido de uma interface implementada na classe que vai usá-lo (segundo algumas recomendações que li internet a fora)?
- Por que dizem não ser recomendável utilizar um `trait` sem implementar `interface`?
- Devo implementar uma interface numa `classe abstrata`, visto que a própria classe abstrata já pode "forçar" a criação de um método para a classe que extenderá a classe abstrata?

Comment: Complicada essa... +1

Comment: Pergunta legal, estou com preguiça de dar uma resposta longa. Não sei se o problema é ter várias perguntas em uma, mesmo que relacionadas. Acho que responderia se não fosse tão ampla.

Comment: Que isso, @bigown. Tá na hora do almoço, mano!

Comment: Você notou a desvantagem de `trait`?  http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.traits.php#107965

Comment: Vixi, @GuilhermeLautert. Pra variar, mais uma complicação da linguagem !

Comment: Eu ja tive colegas que disseram "Trait é mais uma gambiara do PHP, dessa vez para disser que tem herança múltipla", eu não posso disser nada nunca necessitei desse tipo de herança.

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Qual a diferença entre Classes e Interfaces?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/115695/qual-a-diferen%c3%a7a-entre-classes-e-interfaces)

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Traits podem ser vistos quase como uma automatização do `Ctrl+C` e `Ctrl+V`. Essa definição pode parecer grosseira, mas na verdade traits podem ser bastante úteis se usados com cuidado em situações específicas (mais sobre isso abaixo).

O recomendável é que você continue usando interfaces para definir **contratos** (como uma documentação do projeto) e classes abstratas para implementar o código **base** desses contratos, deixando alguns métodos mais específicos para as suas classes-filha implementarem. Enfim, se a *hierarquia* de classes pra seu projeto é importante, continue fazendo desse jeito.

**E quanto aos traits?**

Eles definitivamente não servem para definir contratos. Traits ignoram completamente a hierarquia de classes. Use-os para definir comportamentos muito específicos, que possam ser reutilizados por tipos diferentes de objeto. Entre outras coisas, eles são bem úteis para classes que implementam contratos que se repetem diversas vezes.

Por exemplo: imagine que você tenha as seguintes classes base:

- Jogador
- Veículo
- Arma
- Inimigo
- Cenario

E as seguintes classes filha:

- Rafael `extends` Jogador
- Carro `extends` Veículo
- Moto `extends` Veículo
- Magnum `extends` Arma
- AR-15 `extends` Arma
- Faca `extends` Arma
- Soldado `extends` Inimigo
- Monstro `extends` Inimigo
- Agua `extends` Cenario
- Fogo `extends` Cenario
- ...
- TanqueDeGuerra `extends` Arma ou Veículo?? E se ele puder ser controlado? É um Jogador também? Olha! Ele também pode receber dano!

Num caso como esse, traits seriam úteis para definir métodos e propriedades bem específicos que podem ser **usados** por diversos objetos de tipos diferentes. Por exemplo:

```
//Pode ser type-hinted
Interface RecebeDano {
    protected $vida;
    public function foiAcertado($dano);
}

Interface CausaDano {
    protected $dano;
    public function acertou(RecebeDano $alvo);
}

//Pode ser usado pelas classes Jogador (com as mãos),
//Arma (todas), TanqueDeGuerra e Fogo (item do cenário)
Trait ImplementsCausaDano {
    protected $dano = 10; //Pode ser sobrescrito pela classe
    public function acertou(RecebeDano $alvo) {
        $alvo->foiAcertado($this->dano);
    }
}
```

> "Ah, cara, mas isso eu posso fazer com classe abstrata!"

Bom, vamos com calma aí. Você só pode estender **uma única** classe abstrata. Ou seja, ela claramente define uma relação de pai-filho. Se você quer forçar a hierarquia das classes, beleza. Porém, se você precisa de uma estrutura mais flexível (como o exemplo do tanque acima), traits são o melhor caminho.

**Importante:**

Os métodos das traits são avaliados como se tivessem sido definidos na própria classe que os usa, ou seja: ele tem prioridade sobre um método de uma classe pai com o mesmo nome.

A única entidade que pode sobrescrever um método de um trait é a própria classe que o usa, ou outra trait que tenha o mesmo método. Se a classe que usa os traits não definir explicitamente qual método prevalece, isso vai causar um conflito.

Nesse caso, o PHP oferece a seguinte sintaxe para resolvê-los:

```
class Classe {
    use TraitA, TraitB {
        TraitA::metodoDuplicado insteadof TraitB;
    }
}
```

Para finalizar, se você quiser lembrar do que cada estrutura pretende ser, pode observar a semântica dos comandos que você escreve:

Interface você **implementa:**

> Ela é um contrato. Ela não pode implementar nada, apenas definir, mas o que ela
>   define você **tem que** seguir.

Classe abstrata você **estende:** (herda)

> É um pai. Ele vai te ajudar no que você precisar para constituir a sua base, porém algumas coisas você vai ter que fazer sozinho.

Trait você **usa:**

> Ela é uma ferramenta. Você pode usá-la para o bem ou para o mal. "Com grandes poderes vêm grandes responsabilidades." (Ben, Tio)

Comment: +1 Ótimo exemplo e explicação, lembrarei deste exemplo com certeza.

Answer (score 9):

Não vou entrar por fazer documentação pois cada caso está mais do que documentado, vou apenas tentar passar a minha experiência na minha resposta.

A utilização depende da implementação e do que se quer atingir.

Uma `classe abstract` utilizo muito quando quero definir um *padrão* ou um `mecanismo` onde posso ter reutilização de código. A classe que o *estenda* tem de base para a sua implementação o código associado. Ou seja: Definir um contrato com alguma lógica implícita.

Uma interface utilizo quando quero definir um contrato que um determinado mecanismo tem de utilizar para o mesmo funcionar e especialmente para o identificar como do tipo da interface que implementa. Lógico que a opção acontece quando não preciso de definir um contrato com lógica associada no que respeita a código, com a excepção das constantes.

É comum, mas mais uma vez depende muito do pretendido, utilizar uma `classe abstract` com uma `interface` ao mesmo tempo. No entanto isso é decisão de implementação sendo que e por exemplo com o `instanceof` pode saber de ambos.

Quanto aos `traits` e não querendo utilizar definições trasncrevo:

> Traits are a mechanism for code reuse in single inheritance languages
>   such as PHP. A Trait is intended to reduce some limitations of single
>   inheritance by enabling a developer to reuse sets of methods freely in
>   several independent classes living in different class hierarchies.

Ou seja, é mais um mecanismo pelo qual podemos definir um contrato com código associado e que se orienta mais para uma nova metadologia que se tenta inserir a prazo no PHP.

Na utilização de `traits` tenho obtido alguns **conflitos** porque quando utilizamos `traits` diferentes e se um dos métodos tiver o mesmo nome em ambos, vais obter erro o que me obriga a uma declaração de nomes muito precisa e em projectos grandes costuma ser comum assim como um problema.

É importante ainda dizer que não é possível instanciar directamente qualquer um dos mecanismos sem os implementar em classes que os estendam ou implementem.

Comment: Mas, ainda assim, podemos acessar métodos estáticos dos traits (o que acaba criando algumas confusões entre classes e Traits para quem vê o código, sem ver a declaração da classe ou trait)

Comment: E você citou um ponto importante: "o conflito de nomes entre os metódos dos traits". Ou seja, nada adianta ter uma interface para o trait, já que teria que renomear um método por causa de um conflito :\

Comment: @WallaceMaxters sim qualquer um dos mecanismos tem as suas questões, a experiência é que nos define... eles estão lá é utilizar o que se adapta melhor... eu não digo não a nada especialmente quando me impoe certas utilizações... mas aos traits  tenho dito "não" sempre que posso. talvez pelo hábito.

Comment: @WallaceMaxters o que queres dizer com "Gostaria realmente de um ponto de vista mais amplo"...