# Qual a diferença entre Classes e Interfaces?

Tags: php, classes, interface

Qual a diferença entre **classes** e **interfaces**?

Já li que aparentemente a diferença de interfaces é pq elas são 100% pública, mas eu não faço ideia.

Alguém poderia explicar a diferença entre elas?

Comment: Sugiro dar uma olhada nessa pergunta http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/2913/em-orienta%C3%A7%C3%A3o-a-objetos-por-que-interfaces-s%C3%A3o-%C3%BAteis. Tem bastante coisa sobre interfaces lá e tem inclusive uma resposta usando PHP. Isso pode te ajudar a ter uma ideia melhor sobre o que são interfaces e porque elas são diferentes das classes.

Comment: Resumindo, interface é uma classe onde define-se um contrato de quais métodos devem existir na classe que usar tal interface.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Toda *Interface* é uma classe, mas nem toda *classe* é uma interface, o uso de interfaces em PHP é semelhante ao de outras linguagens de programação.

Uma interface em base serve pra definir *alguns padrões* que a classe que vai implementá-la deve ter. Geralmente usamos pra garantir um certo comportamento das outras classes que vierem a implementar uma determinada *Interface*.

Os métodos de uma interface são *100% públicos* como você mencionou, porque você nunca vai *executar* uma *interface*, ela serve de *esqueleto* pra outra classe, ou seja é pra determinar métodos "padrões usáveis" pelo objeto, não teria sentido declarar algo `private` ou `protected` na interface, já que isto só iria rodar "internamente".

### Classes

No PHP5 estão a inclusão de [visibility](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/language.oop5.visibility.php), classes e metodos [abstract](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/language.oop5.abstract.php) e [final](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/language.oop5.final.php), [métodos mágicos](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/language.oop5.magic.php) adicionais, [interfaces](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/language.oop5.interfaces.php) (como citei anteriormente) e [clonagem](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/language.oop5.cloning.php).

O PHP trata objetos da mesma maneira que referencias ou manipuladores, significando que cada variável contém uma referencia a um objeto ao invés de uma cópia de todo o objeto. Veja [Objetos e Referencias](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.references.php).

### Interfaces de Objetos

Interfaces de Objetos permite a criação de código que especifica quais métodos e variáveis uma classe deve implementar, sem ter que definir como esses métodos serão tratados.

Interfaces são definidas usando a palavra-chave interface, da mesma maneira que uma classe comum, mas sem nenhum dos métodos ter seu conteúdo definido.

Todos os métodos declarados em uma interface devem ser public. Essa é a natureza de uma interface.

### Usando `implements`

Para implementar uma interface, o operador `implements` é usado. Todos os métodos na interface devem ser implementados na classe; não fazer isso resultará em um erro fatal. Classes podem implementar mais de uma interface se assim for desejado, separando cada interface com uma vírgula.

Exemplo:

- Usando uma Interface

  ```
    <?php

    // Declara a interface 'iTemplate'
    interface iTemplate
    {
        public function setVariable($name, $var);
        public function getHtml($template);
    }

    // Implementa a interface
    // Isso funcionará
    class Template implements iTemplate
    {
        private $vars = array();

        public function setVariable($name, $var)
        {
            $this->vars[$name] = $var;
        }

        public function getHtml($template)
        {
            foreach($this->vars as $name => $value) {
                $template = str_replace('{' . $name . '}', $value, $template);
            }

            return $template;
        }
    }

    // Isso NÃO funcionará
    // Fatal error: Class BadTemplate contains 1 abstract methods
    // and must therefore be declared abstract (iTemplate::getHtml)
    class BadTemplate implements iTemplate
    {
        private $vars = array();

        public function setVariable($name, $var)
        {
            $this->vars[$name] = $var;
        }
    }
  ```
- Interfaces estendíveis

  ```
    <?php
    interface a
    {
        public function foo();
    }

    interface b extends a
    {
        public function baz(Baz $baz);
    }

    // Isto irá funcionar
    class c implements b
    {
        public function foo()
        {
        }

        public function baz(Baz $baz)
        {
        }
    }

    // Isto não irá funcionar e resultará em um erro fatal
    class d implements b
    {
        public function foo()
        {
        }

        public function baz(Foo $foo)
        {
        }
    }
  ```
- Interface com herança múltipla

  ```
    <?php
    interface a
    {
        public function foo();
    }

    interface b
    {
        public function bar();
    }

    interface c extends a, b
    {
        public function baz();
    }

    class d implements c
    {
        public function foo()
        {
        }

        public function bar()
        {
        }

        public function baz()
        {
        }
    }
  ```
- Interfaces com constantes

  ```
    <?php
    interface a
    {
        const b = 'Interface constant';
    }

    // Imprime: Interface constant
    echo a::b;


    // Isto não funcionará porque não é permitido
    // sobreescrever constantes.
    class b implements a
    {
        const b = 'Class constant';
    }
  ```

### Regras de compatibilidade de assinaturas

Ao substituir um método, sua assinatura deve ser compatível com o método pai, caso contrário um erro fatal é emitido. Uma assinatura é compatível se respeitar as regras de variação, tornar um parâmetro obrigatório opcional, adicionar apenas novos parâmetros opcionais e não restringir, mas apenas relaxar a visibilidade. Isso é conhecido como **Princípio de Substituição de Liskov**, ou **LSP** (para abreviar).

O construtor, e membros private não precisam seguir essas regras de compatibilidade, e portanto não há emissão de erros fatais no caso de assinaturas incompatíveis

---

**Nota:** Até o PHP 5.3.9, um classe não poderia implementar duas interfaces que especifiquem um método com o mesmo nome, pois isso causaria ambiguidade. Versões mais recentes permitem isso desde que os métodos duplicados tenham a mesma assinatura.

Interfaces podem ser estendidas como classes, usando o operador extends.

A classe que implementa a interface precisa ter as mesmas assinaturas de método como as definidas na interface. De outra forma uma erro fatal será lançado.

<sub>Fonte: https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.interfaces.php</sub>