# Qual a importância da interface nesse determinado código?

Tags: php, orientação-a-objetos, interface

Se iremos colocar as funções da interface, também dentro da classe, pra que então criar interface?

Exemplo:

#### Interface

```
interface Teste {
    function olaMundo($texto);
}
```

#### Classe

```
class Testando implements Teste {
    function olaMundo($texto); //Método da interface
}
```

#### Index.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Teste</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <?php
            require_once 'Testando.php';
            $i = new Testando;
            $i->olaMundo("Ola mundo!");
        ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

Aí, no caso, qual foi o papel da interface nesse código?

Comment: A interface te obriga a implementar os métodos na classe.

Comment: Somente serve pra isso, Roberto?

Comment: Relacionada ou duplicada: [Quando devo usar Herança, Classe Abstrata, Interface ou um Trait?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/73449/18246)

Comment: Relacionada ou duplicada: [Classe Abstrata X Interface](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/3603/18246)

Comment: Relacionada ou duplicada: [Em orientação a objetos, por que interfaces são úteis?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/2913/18246)

Comment: Relacionada: [Programar voltado para interface e não para a implementação, por que?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/86484/18246)

Comment: Relacionada ou duplicada: [Como e quando usar Interface?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/107524/18246)

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Qual a diferença entre Classes e Interfaces?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/115695/qual-a-diferen%c3%a7a-entre-classes-e-interfaces)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Neste exemplo específico aparentemente ela tem nenhum papel. Exemplos abstratos demais não costumam ensinar o uso de algo, salvo raros casos. O exemplo pode ser fictício, mas quando se analisa se o conceito está sendo seguido não, pode simplesmente colocar qualquer bobagem. Não é só colocar um conjunto de palavras quaisquer. Em programação contexto é muito importante. O detalhe é que define o que fazer. Nomes significativos são documentação e podem explicar o que está ocorrendo ali. Esse código diz nada a não ser que é um teste, não dá contexto.

Este é um caso que a interface não está tendo utilidade porque ela foi colocada para ilustrar algo sem sentido. Interfaces são úteis para abstrair ideias, para estabelecer contratos quando é necessário. Este caso não é necessário.

Se fosse um caso real nela teria uma ou mais [assinaturas de métodos](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/39870/101) que serviriam como contrato, então o tipo de interface poderia ser usado em algum lugar e toda classe que implemente a interface poderia ser usada em determinado algoritmo. O que é muito esquisito em uma linguagem que prega a tipagem dinâmica, pior, a tipagem fraca, mas a gente já sabe, é PHP, faz parte da filosofia não oficial fazer coisas esquisitas.

Se não tiver uma vantagem, uma função específica, não use. Isso vale pra qualquer coisa. A utilidade se dá em sistemas complexos, onde os contratos precisam ser respeitados.

Algumas perguntas sobre interface disponíveis no site que devem ajudar entender:

- [Em orientação a objetos, por que interfaces são úteis?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/2913/101)
- [Programar voltado para interface e não para a implementação, por quê?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/86484/101)
- [Como e quando usar Interface?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/107524/101)
- [Classe Abstrata X Interface](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/3603/101)
- [Quando devo usar Herança, Classe Abstrata, Interface ou um Trait?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/73449/101)
- [Utilizar muitas interfaces é uma má prática de programação?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/23900/101)
- [É uma prática ruim usar interfaces vazias?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/76511/101)
- [Como e quando devemos usar Interface para documentar sistemas no PHP?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/100489/101)

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/PHP/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Obrigado, bigown, sei que fiz um código bobo, mas com sua resposta e a do LINQ, consegui entender.

Comment: `Exemplos abstratos não costumam ensinar o uso de algo, salvo raros casos` Eu queria poder dar upvote de novo só por essa frase.