# Uma interface é uma variável?

Tags: java, orientação-a-objetos, classes, interface

Tenho algumas dúvidas a respeito de interfaces em relação a maneira que elas são utilizadas.

Eu pensava que a interface não era usada como variável que representa e armazena algum tipo de dado, veja `MinhaInterface mInterface;` ao invés de ter a única finalidade de ser como um contrato das classes que a implementam. No exemplo abaixo é mostrada a interface [NodeList](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/org/w3c/dom/NodeList.html) sendo usada como variável para armazenar outra interface do mesmo tipo que é retornada pelo método `getElementsByTagName()`:

```
NodeList noList = document.getElementsByTagName("minhaTag");
```

Sendo assim, como uma interface pode ser uma variável e qual é diferença da variável de tipo interface em comparação com a variável de tipo classe? A interface pode ser instanciada como uma classe com o comando `new` ou não já que ela pode ser usada como variável?

Comment: Há algumas confusões aí, vou tentar explicar, mas ainda nem sei por onde começar. Exatamente o que é retornado por este método?

Comment: Pelo que entendi do código, a finalidade ainda se manteve, só irá aceitar se o tipo de dado passado para noList estiver "assinado" o contrato, ou seja, se implementar `NodeList`. Você está restringindo que todo dado passado pra esta variável, independente do tipo, atenda o que foi exibido na interface `NodeList`. No fim, a finalidade é a mesma.

Comment: Se entendi certo, quando vc faz `NodeList noList = algo ...` está dizendo que `noList` recebe algo é que um super tipo. Lembre que vc pode especificar um super tipo(interface ou classe abstrata geralmente) em parâmetros de métodos.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Uma interface nunca é uma variável, interface é interface, se quiser generalizar o termo, é um **tipo** de dado que, sim, indica um contrato. Em Java 8 até permite ter algo além do contrato, mas imagino que não seja o caso aqui.

É possível [**declarar** uma variável](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/136279/101) sendo de um tipo `interface` sem problema algum, mas concretamente só se pode **atribuir** um tipo concreto, ou seja, uma classe (em outras linguagens, ou versão mais nova do Java, até pode outras coisas). Obviamente que a classe que for usada para instanciar um objeto concreto precisa ser compatível com a interface declarada, portanto ser um tipo que implemente a interface.

Então esse método usado aí deve retornar um objeto concreto que é conforme com a interface `NodeList`.

No caso a variável `noList` só poderá acessar os membros presentes na interface (que o objeto certamente tem, pela conformidade estabelecida na classe). Para acessar outros membros do objeto concreto, só fazendo um *cast* no objeto. A interface não tem conhecimento sobre os outros membros.

Pode ser que o retorno declarado do método seja uma interface, mas o retorno real será um objeto concreto que é conforme com a interface do seu retorno. Obviamente que se essa interface não é `NodeList`, deverá ser uma outra que está em conformidade com `NodeList` (derivada dela).

Imaginando que seria esse o [método documentando](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/org/w3c/dom/Element.html#getElementsByTagName-java.lang.String-) então o tipo retornado é [`NodeList`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/org/w3c/dom/NodeList.html). Assinatura dele:

```
NodeList getElementsByTagName(String name)
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Java/Interface/NodeList.java).

Lá lista a classe [`IOMetadataNode`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/javax/imageio/metadata/IIOMetadataNode.html) como uma classe que a implementa. Então possivelmente o método `getElementsByTagName()` retorna um objeto concreto desta classe. Mas pode ser outra coisa, nada garante isso, pode até mudar um dia e isso "não é assunto seu" (o uso da interface diz isso).

## Como vou saber qual é o objeto concreto que retorna da classe se não tem na documentação? Tenho que olhar os fontes deste método?

Na verdade a ideia do uso da interface é justamente não precisar pensar sobre o tipo concreto. Não é do seu interesse saber, use a interface e pronto. Em muitos raros casos saber o tipo será útil e provavelmente fará alguma gambiarra com esta informação. Em geral [programamos para a interface e não para a implementação](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/86484/101).

Answer (score 9):

#### TL;DR;

**Não**. Uma coisa não tem nada a ver com a outra.

---

Você está confundindo algumas coisas.

Primeiramente, no trecho abaixo, quando você se refere a "variável"

> Eu pensava que a interface não era usada como variável que representa e armazena algum tipo de dado

está querendo se referir a um **tipo**.

Um pequeno exemplo, caso você ainda confunda os conceitos.

```
Tipo variavel = new Tipo();
//Ou como no caso de usar interface
Interface variavel = new TipoQueImplementaInterface();
```

Veja bem, uma interface **pode** definir o tipo de uma variável, o que acontece é que interfaces **não podem ser instanciadas**. Isso quer dizer que, a interface pode estar do lado esquerdo da declaração, mas **nunca do lado direito**, do lado direito você sempre usa o tipo concreto.

Ex:

```
MinhaInterface var = new MinhaClasseQueImplementaMinhaInterface();
```

Isso, basicamente e dentre outras coisas, permite que a variável `var` receba qualquer tipo que implemente **`MinhaInterface`** sem precisar se preocupar com a implementação dos métodos definidos na interface.

Não vou entrar em detalhes sobre como funcionam as interfaces porque já temos respostas boas sobre isso aqui. Vide:

[Em orientação a objetos, por que interfaces são úteis?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/2913/18246)
[Classe Abstrata X Interface](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/3603/18246)
[Em OOP, uma interface pode ter atributos?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/89894/18246)
[Quando devo usar Herança, Classe Abstrata, Interface ou um Trait?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/73449/18246)

Answer (score 3):

No código:

```
NodeList noList = document.getElementsByTagName("minhaTag");
```

`NodeList` é o tipo, nesse caso uma interface.

`noList` é uma variável do tipo `NodeList`.

O fato de você declarar `noList` como um variável do tipo `NodeList` não implica que a interface `NodeList` é agora uma variável. São coisas distintas. O mesmo vale quando declara-se uma variável como `String`, veja:

```
String texto;
```

O fato de você declarar texto como `String`, não torna `String` uma variável. Portanto, `NodeList` e `String` são tipos, independentemente se são classes concretas, abstratas, interfaces ou enums.

Isso que escrevi pode parecer muito óbvio, mas sua pergunta está um pouco misturada e fica complicado saber ao certo onde está a sua dúvida.

O que deve ficar claro é que a chamada `document.getElementsByTagName("minhaTag");` deve, obrigatoriamente, retornar um objeto de uma determinada classe concreta que implementa a interface `NodeList`.