# O que significa uma variável do tipo de uma classe abstrata?

Tags: java, variáveis, tipagem, classes-abstratas

Estudando *design pattern* eu vi uma coisa que não entendi muito bem o que significa, quando temos uma variável do tipo de uma classe abstrata o que isso significa exatamente?

Exemplo:

```
ClasseAbstrata variavel;
```

O que significa quado temos este tipo e igualamos a nova variável a uma outra classe?

Exemplo do código que eu tenho aqui que compila mas eu não entendo ele muito bem:

```
FabricaAbstrata fabricaCor = ReprodutorFabrica.getFabrica("COR");
```

- Essa fabrica abstrata tem o método `getCor()`.
- O método `getFabrica()` de `ReprodutorFabrica` retorna um criador de um tipo de objeto, no caso retorna o criador de cor.

Comment: Acho que isso responde: [Uma interface é uma variável?](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/138320/91)

Comment: Alguma das respostas abaixo resolveu o seu problema? Acha que pode aceitar uma delas? Veja o [tour] como fazer isso, se ainda não sabe como fazê-lo. Assim ajuda a comunidade identificando qual foi a melhor solução para você. Só pode aceitar apenas uma delas, mas pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo.

Answer (score 6):

Eu quase fechei como duplicata desta: [Uma interface é uma variável?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/138320/101). É essencialmente a mesma coisa.

`ReprodutorFabrica` não retorna alguma coisa porque é uma classe, classes não retornam. Quem retorna é o `getFabrica()`. Esse retorna um objeto que é de uma classe concreta derivada de `FabricaAbstrata`. Note que eu nem sei o que esse método retorna, mas só pode ser isso.

O que interessa aí é o objeto concreto, a variável ser de um tipo significa que ela pode armazenar qualquer objeto que seja desse tipo, incluindo suas derivadas. Mas a variável não pode ter um objeto concreto que seja exatamente um tipo abstrato, esses são tipos incompletos e não podem ser instanciados. É tudo uma questão de contrato.

Só podemos [atribuir](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/136279/101) um objeto de uma classe que esteja de acordo com o tipo do variável, ou seja, tem que ser do mesmo tipo ou tenha herdade ou implementado o tipo da variável.

Nesse caso podemos dizer que a [classe abstrata está funcionando como interface](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/3603/101). Isso é o que se chama [programar para a interface e não para a implementação](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/86484/101).

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Java/Conceptual.md).

Answer (score 3):

Um conceito básico em Orientação a objetos é a herança. Boa partes dos padrões de projeto são implementados com base nesses conceitos, onde uma classe é a base para implementação de outras classes ou mesmo garante que um conjunto de instancias tenha um ponto em comum que possa ser utilizado em vários contextos, esse ponto em comum é geralmente o que chamamos de assinatura ou contrato e a maioria das vezes é a classe base.

Um exemplo trivial:

```
class Carro
{
   private int nivelCombustivel;
   void SubirNivel(int valor)
   {
       this.nivelCombustivel += valor; 
   }
}
```

Uma classe que herda da classe basica Carro:

```
class Gol extends Carro
{
  private string nitro;
  private int motor=1;     
}
```

De uma forma geral, é bem facil e comum fazer esse tipo de coisa, um local onde eu tenho uma classe mais básica que complementa a anterior adicionando um comportamento. Um outro fator ainda mais importante é que por possuir a mesma assinatura base, em todos os lugares onde eu posso usar a classe carro, eu tambem posso usar instâncias da classe Gol.

No entanto, imagine agora que você comece a ter muitos tipos de carro e que precise retonar o tipo de carro adequado de acordo com um parametro fornecido pelo usuário, vamos supor que seja o motor e que somente o Fusca tenha um motor 2.0 :)

```
class Fusca extends Carro
{
  private string nitro;
  private motor = 2;

}
```

Então, no código, toda vez que o carro fosse solicitado você provavelmente teria um if:

```
if(tipoMotor == 2)
   return new Fusca();
```

E sairia repetindo esse trecho de código em vários locais onde essa logica de seleção fosse necessária, isso é um indicador de que você está precisando de um padrão, então, vamos para a fabrica de carros. :)

Opa, toda vez que vou retornar o tipo de carro, o usuario vai informar o tipo de motor e eu vou realizar alguma logica para devolver uma instancia adequada de carro. Bem, existem alguns problemas ai:

1) O tipo de classe que devo instanciar vai depender do tipo de parametro fornecido pelo usuario e isso não pode ficar fixo no codigo.
2) O trecho de codigo que seleciona o tipo de classe vai ter que ser usado em todos os lugares que vão instanciar carros.
3) O numero de carros pode crescer e eu vou precisar ficar alterando todos os lugares que usarem essa logica para montar uma instancia do carro.

Bom, esse caso ai está para uma Factory ou Fabrica, como você andou pesquisando. Nesse caso, uma fabrica é basicamente um objeto que é responsável por guardar a lógica de construção de outros objetos quando essa logica é complexa, no nosso caso, o método que vai retornar o carro.

E estamos com sorte, como todos os carros herdam de uma classe basica Carro, no podemos usar ela como retorno de nossa fábrica, algo assim:

```
class FabricaCarros{
   public static Carro GetCarro(int motor)
   {
      if(motor == 2)
       return new Fusca();
      else return new Gol();
   }
}
```

Repare que eu posso chamar o metodo GetCarro onde eu quiser e ele vai me fornecer o tipo de carro adequado. As classes externas não precisam conhecer a implementação da classe fusca ou classe gol porque as duas herdam de Carro.

Por exemplo, se eu tiver uma classe PostoGasolina que instancia uma novo carro e  abastece o carro com +2 de combustivel, então eu teria algo do tipo:

classe PostoGasolina{
   public Carro GetCarroAbastecido(int motor)
   {
     Carro car = FabricaCarros.GetCarro(motor);
     car.SubirNivel(2);
     return car;
   }
}

Repare que a classe que consome o serviço da fábrica não conhece a implementação do carro que está abastecendo, então, você pode incluir quantas regras quiser no metodo da fábrica, para quantos modelos quiser e o sistema vai continuar abastecendo.

Mas, vamos complicar ainda mais as coisas :D Agora, suas classes de carros são parte de um framework para criação de jogos de corrida e você vai vender seus componentes por ai. Então, vamos a alguns problemas:

1) De cara, a Classe carro, por ser uma classe normal, pode ser instanciada a qualquer momento por qualquer pessoa que pegar seu framework, porém, a classe carro não faz nada!! ela nem tem motor!! as regras estão na fabrica e os programadores(usuarios) não devia instanciar carros sem herdar da classe basica :(

2) Como as regras para o tipo de carro sempre dependem do motor, você quer obrigar todo mundo a criar classes novas para novos tipos de carros.

3) No entanto, você ainda precisa de uma parte do codigo (SubirNivel) para abastecer seu carro independente do modelo e quer isso na classe carro e como sua classe posto é muito bonita porque o codigo não precisa conhecer a implementação das classes que herdam da classe carro, você quer manter as coisas assim sem mudar o resto do codigo, então você so precisa obrigar as novas implementações de carro a terem a mesma assinatura e comportamento.

Bom, você pode pensar numa interface, porem, interfaces são usadas quando você quer obrigar uma implementação concreta a manter uma assinatura, mas, não permite código na base.

Então, eu não poderia usar meu método SubirNivel em carro :(

É nesse tipo de cenário que você usa uma classe abstrata:

```
abstract class Carro
{
   private int nivelCombustivel;
   void SubirNivel(int valor)
   {
       this.nivelCombustivel += valor; 
   }
}
```

Basicamente, eu coloquei a classe carro como abstrata. Tem diversas consequencias, mas, antes de tudo, lembre que eu ainda herdo as outras classes dela.

Quando você criar uma classe abstrata você faz o seguinte:

1) Não pode instanciar a classe (ex.: nada de new Carro())

2) Se não pode instanciar, tem que sempre que herdar para outra classe e implementar o necessário la e ai sim você instancia (ou seja, so pode instanciar classes que herdam da classe abstrata (ex.: gol). Nos dizemos que as classes que implementam a herança são as implementações concretas da classe abstrata.

Tipo um carro é qualquer coisa, mas, um gol é um gol. :)

3) Em uma interface você so especifica a assinatura/contrato, em uma classe abstrata, você pode ter um trecho de código que vai ser levado para as implementações concretas (por isso posso continuar usando SubirNivel).

Então, seguindo os 2 padrões que te expliquei, o que você provavelmente tem é uma Fabrica que constrói uma fabrica.

**Nos exemplos acima, eu tenho apenas um nível de Fabrica por que o meu padrão retorna ja a implementação concreta da classe carro. No seu caso, você provavelmente tem mais de um tipo de fábrica para gerar a construção do objeto cor.

Logo, o seu primeiro nivel retorna a implementação concreta da fabrica do objeto cor que por sua vez retorna a implementação concreta da Cor.**

Você provavelmente está aplicando o mesmo padrão porque existe complexidade até mesmo na criação da Fabrica do objeto cor.

```
FabricaAbstrata fabricaCor = ReprodutorFabrica.getFabrica("COR"); // retorna a implementação concreta uma fabrica da classe cor.

Cor c = fabricarCor.GetCor() // usa a fabrica retornada para retornar a implementação concreta da Cor.
```

Você pode ter isso, porque tem suporte a esquemas de cores diferentes e a fabrica de cores precisa retornar os tipos de cores corretos para cada tipo de suporte (vga, xvga, svga, etc...). Para depois, usar a fabrica correta para retornar a cor. É como se aplicasse recursivamente o padrão Factory :) se é que isso existe :D