# Declaração do Arraylist?

Tags: java

Eu vi alguns exemplos do uso e alguns usam diferente a declaração do ArrayList, `List<>` e `ArrayList<>` no inicio.

Comment: ArrayList é a implementação propriamente dita, que implementa a interface List. Por isso você pode iniciar desta forma: `List<type> list = new ArrayList<>();`

Comment: Complete a pergunta por favor.

Comment: Veja essa pergunta [Uma interface é uma variável?](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/138320/18246). Aliás, deveríamos marcar como duplicata? Já que esta responde a dele...

Comment: @jbueno verdade, a resposta lá explica exatamente a dúvida.

Comment: Queria saber se tem alguma diferença.

Comment: @user50289 bem vindo ao Soft, acesse a Ajuda e faça o Tour para entender como funciona esta comunidade e como deve perguntar e lidar com as respostas e comentários.

Comment: @user50289, gostaria de adiciona um adendo sobre ArrayList: [aqui](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/195006/6789)

Answer (score 2):

As duas declarações abaixo têm o mesmo efeito.

```
List<String> lista = new ArrayList<String>();
ArrayList<String> lista2 = new ArrayList<String>();
```

A única diferença é que a variável `lista` poderá receber outras implementações de `List`. Por exemplo:

```
lista = new LinkedList<String>();
```

Como você definiu o tipo da variável `List<String>`, isso é completamente possível. Se fosse com a variável `lista2`, isso não seria possível.

Não vou entrar em detalhes nisso porque tem muitas respostas aqui no site que falam sobre (linkei algumas delas abaixo), mas a diferença entre os dois é que **`List`** é a interface, **`ArrayList`** é a implementação - a classe implementa a interface.

Interfaces não podem ser instanciadas, elas servem apenas para definir um contrato nas classes que a implementarem.

Logo, você **não pode** fazer

```
List<String> lista = new List<String>(); // É impossível instanciar uma interface
```

Porém, é completamente possível fazer

```
List<String> lista = new ArrayList<String>();
```

Você sempre pode usar a interface do lado esquerdo da declaração, isso é uma coisa muito comum em linguagens orientadas a objetos.

Ex.:

```
List<String> lista = new ArrayList<String>();
List<String> lista2 = new LinkedList<String>();

/* Tanto ArrayList, quanto LinkedList implementam List. Por isso a declaração
pode ser feita desta forma */
```

---

Você pode aprender mais sobre interfaces nas perguntas abaixo

[Uma interface é uma variável?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/138320/18246)
[Em orientação a objetos, por que interfaces são úteis?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/2913/18246)
[Classe Abstrata X Interface](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/3603/18246)
[Em OOP, uma interface pode ter atributos?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/89894/18246)
[Quando devo usar Herança, Classe Abstrata, Interface ou um Trait?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/73449/18246)

Comment: gostaria de adiciona um adendo sobre ArrayList: [aqui](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/195006/6789)

Comment: Desculpe, vou remover e colocar no pergunta. Desculpe!