# Instanciar interface - Pra que serve?

Tags: java, spring, interface

Aprendi na faculdade e em todos materiais que vi que a interface serve  para definir um padrão que as classes devem seguir e interfaces NÃO podem ser instanciadas. Entretanto me deparei com projetos que possuem uma interface e uma classe q implementa essa interface. Entretanto quando é instanciado para utilização, é instanciado a interface com a anotação @Autowired e sem new em vez da classe que a implementou.

Exemplo:

```
@Autowired
ThingRepository rep;
```

sendo ThingRepository uma interface que tem uma classe ThingRepositoryImpl correspondente a implementação da interface.

Alguem sabe qual é o objetivo dessa pratica?

Comment: Relacionado: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/138320/27190

Comment: @DenerCarvalho Eu diria que é até duplicata mesmo. Não voto porque fecharia a pergunta e gostaria de mais opiniões.

Comment: @bigown apesar de eu questionar no final da minha pergunta sobre a instanciação da interface, mas a minha pergunta questiona outros assuntos também.

Comment: @DenerCarvalho o importante para classificar como duplicata é que se lá tem uma resposta que responde o que foi perguntado aqui, não importa se respondeu outras coisas junto. Duplicata não quer dizer que a pergunta tem que ser igualzinha, imposta se responde. Eu acho que sim, mas não tenho 100% de certeza para dar voto final.

Comment: @AnthonyAccioly Obrigado pela resposta. Era exatamente essa minha duvida. Então no final das contas ele esta usando a implementação ao invés da interface. Na hora de usar. Eu não poderia usar "ThingRepositoryImpl rep" ao invés de "ThingRepository rep", faria mais sentido pra mim.

Comment: Como o Anthony Accioly falou, o Spring é inteligente o suficiente para encontrar uma classe que implementa a interface e instanciá-la.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A anotação [`@Autowired`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/annotation/Autowired.html) não está instanciando uma interface.

Não existe uma maneira de instanciar uma interface uma vez que a interface é apenas um "contrato" (no Java 8 existem [métodos *default*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/defaultmethods.html) com implementações concretas mas isso é assunto para outra conversa). O mais próximo que você pode chegar de "instanciar uma interface" em Java é instanciar uma [classe anônima](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/anonymousclasses.html) que implementa uma interface [conforme a resposta do Piovezan](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/147306/100). Mas não é isso que o Spring está fazendo nesse exemplo.

O Spring na verdade cria uma instância de `ThingRepositoryImpl‌`​. Adicionalmente o framework pode também embrulhar a implementação com *proxies* ou fazer *[weaving](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/aop.html#aop-aj-ltw)* para disponibilizar aspectos como controle de transação para a aplicação.

Nesse exemplo você está usando a interface como [tipo de referência](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/interfaceAsType.html). A ideia é esconder a implementação para tornar o *design* da aplicação mais flexível. `ThingRepository` é utilizado como tipo de referência pelo mesmo motivo que costumamos expor a interface `List` e não um dos seus tipos concretos como `ArrayList` nas APIs:

```
List<String> list = buildList();

public List<String> buildList() {
    List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
    // você pode trocar a implementacao para LinkedList sem  
    // mudanças no restante da aplicação
    return list;
}
```

Assuma que `ThingRepositoryImpl` hoje implemente persistência utilizando o banco de dados MySQL. Daqui a um tempo você pode querer utilizar o MongoDB ao invés do MySQL (ou quem sabe utilizar MySQL para alguns clientes e MongoDB para outros). Utilizando a interface `ThingRepository` como tipo de referência você está escondendo a implementação concreta do serviço. Dessa forma você pode sempre criar uma nova implementação de `ThingRepository` (e.g., `ThingRepositoryMongoDBImpl`) e substituí-la com o Spring de forma transparente para as classes que hoje dependem desse serviço. Isso não seria possível se você referenciasse a classe `ThingRepositoryImpl` diretamente, nesse caso você teria que modificar as classes "clientes".

Em suma, existe uma máxima "[Programe para a interface, não para a implementação](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/86484/100)" que casa bem com o serviço de [Injeção de Dependência](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/20785/100) disponibilizado pelo Spring. Combinando ambas as coisas o *design* da sua aplicação se torna mais flexível (i.e., torná-se mais fácil evoluir a aplicação).

Answer (score 7):

O Java permite instanciar classes anônimas que implementam uma determinada interface. É como se você dissesse "crie uma classe, não importa o nome dela, desde que implemente a interface que estou informando". Aí você abre chaves e preenche dentro delas o(s) método(s) que implementam o contrato dessa interface.

```
MinhaInterface variavel = new MinhaInterface() {
    @Override
    public void meuMetodo() {
        // Uma implementação qualquer
    }
};
```

A utilidade mais comum é quando você precisa passar um objeto que implementa uma determinada interface como parâmetro para um método (em outras palavras, o tipo do parâmetro do método é uma interface) e você não quer ter o trabalho de criar uma nova classe em um arquivo `.java` à parte só para fazer instanciar e usar nesse ponto. Uma classe anônima serve, pois o que importa é a implementação, que provavelmente só vai ser usada naquela única situação.