# Por que posso atribuir uma instância de uma classe a uma variável cujo tipo é a interface?

Tags: java, memória, interface

Exatamente a que se refere quando eu crio um objeto na memória, porém associo ele a varável `a1` do tipo interface (`AreaCalculavel`)? Estou um pouco confuso, veja abaixo o exemplo.

```
package exercicio0101;

public class Aplicacao {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        double area;

        AreaCalculavel a1 = new Quadrado(10);
        area = a1.calculaArea();
        System.out.println("Area do Quadrado: " + area);

        AreaCalculavel a2 = new Circunferencia(5);
        area = a2.calculaArea();
        System.out.println("Area da Circunferencia: " + area);

        AreaCalculavel a3 = new Retangulo(10, 2.5);
        area = a3.calculaArea();
        System.out.println("Area do Retangulo: " + area);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Interfaces são contratos, então elas só existem para controlar acesso aos membros de um objeto, elas não determinam o que realmente é o objeto, só o que eles são capazes de fazer (mesmo quando tem uma implementação *default* de métodos nela). Só classes concretas podem criar objetos e elas que definem como o objeto será estruturado na memória. Então a interface não tem nenhum papel na definição do *layout* da memória, só as 3 classes usadas criam objetos.

Outro ponto importante a notar é que objetos que possuem interfaces são sempre por referência e por isso na variável só terá um ponteiro que indica onde o objeto está de fato, desta forma a variável tem um tamanho fixo (sempre 4 ou 8 bytes dependendo da arquitetura que está rodando). Não poderia ser diferente porque você só pode ter objetos de tamanhos potencialmente diferentes através de [indireção](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/181032/101), mantendo assim o mesmo tamanho na variável. O objeto mesmo fica em outra área ([*heap*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/3797/101)).

Inclusive tudo isso poderia ser feito com apenas uma variável, ou até mesmo sem nenhuma, mas o que quero dizer é que as 3 variáveis que guardam o objeto são compatíveis e como o valor não é usado mais poderia reaproveitar a variável, ou nem ter a variável.

Só atente que a variável poderá acessar só o que a interface deixa, mesmo que objeto nela tenha vários outros membros disponíveis, lembrando que ela é um contrato do que pode acessar, e eu entendo que ela tenha o método `calcularArea()` e mais nada, então é só isso que poderá chamar nela (até poderá acessar outras coisas do objeto se fizer um *cast*, mas quase sempre que faz um *cast* algo está errado).

Talvez precise estudar sobre hierarquia de tipos para entender melhor esses conceitos. Não é simples entender quando falta vários outros fundamentos, porque para cada explicação exige um conhecimento. A construção do conhecimento flui melhor quando se aprende primeiro os conceitos fundamentais para aplicá-los depois.

Para entender melhor sobre interface:

- [Uma interface é uma variável?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/138320/101)
- [Como e quando usar Interface?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/107524/101) (cheio de *links* sobre o assunto)
- [Programar voltado para interface e não para a implementação, por quê?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/86484/101)
- [Classes que implementam interfaces são consideradas subclasses?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/152266/101)
- [Em orientação a objetos, por que interfaces são úteis?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/2913/101)

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Java/Conceptual.md).