# O uso de traits substitui o papel da herança múltipla?

Tags: php, orientação-a-objetos, herança, trait

O que acontece se eu usar em uma classe duas *traits* diferentes, e ambas possuírem um método com o mesmo nome, porém implementações diferentes neste método?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

De uma certa forma sim. Não totalmente porque um [*trait*](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.traits.php) não pode ter estado. Mas você consegue obter subtipo e subclasse de vários tipos com ele.

## Conflitos de nomes

Se a classe tiver uma implementação do método ele será considerado e as implementações dos *traits* serão desconsiderados. O mesmo vale se o método no *trait* não tem implementação. Obviamente a classe é obrigado implementar, a não ser que outro *trait* forneça uma implementação conceitualmente aceitável.

Quando há conflito um erro é gerado e o código não funciona. É possível resolver o conflito e permitir o funcionamento correto. A documentação mostra como é resolvido:

```
trait A {
    public function smallTalk() {
        echo 'a';
    }
    public function bigTalk() {
        echo 'A';
    }
}

trait B {
    public function smallTalk() {
        echo 'b';
    }
    public function bigTalk() {
        echo 'B';
    }
}

class Talker {
    use A, B {
        B::smallTalk insteadof A;
        A::bigTalk insteadof B;
    }
}

class Aliased_Talker {
    use A, B {
        B::smallTalk insteadof A;
        A::bigTalk insteadof B;
        B::bigTalk as talk;
    }
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/4msBFa). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/akjlmylm-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/PHP/OOP/Trait.php).

Portanto há uma sintaxe que determinada qual dos *traits* ambíguos deve ser usado em cada situação. Nesse exemplo o `smallTalk()` usado será do *trait* `B`. Já o `bigTalk()` será de `A`. E se usar um nono método chamado `talk()` que será o mesmo que chamar o `bigTalk()` de `B`. O `smallTalk()` de `A` não é acessível.

Answer (score 2):

Suponhamos que você tenha duas ou mais classes que precisam usar um método em comum, pode ser possível usar Traits.

Traits são mecanismos que ajudam na reutilização de código, e servem perfeitamente para resolver o problema da falta de herança múltipla, pois o PHP não suporta herança múltipla. Traits foi disponibilizado a partir da versão 5.4.0 do PHP.

Uma Trait não pode ser instanciada ou ter seus métodos chamados diretamente e devem ser incorporados a uma classe. 
A sintaxe para incorporado uma trait em uma classe é através da palavra reservada `use`.

```
class Base {
        public function sayStack() {
            echo 'Stack ';
        }
    }

    trait SayOverflow {
        public function sayOverflow() {
            parent::sayStack();
            echo 'Overflow!';
        }
    }

    class MyStackOverflow extends Base {
        use SayOverflow;
    }

    $o = new MyStackOverflow();
    $o->sayOverflow();
```

Referências:
[Documentação php.net](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/language.oop5.traits.php)
[Quando devo usar Herança, Classe Abstrata, Interface ou um Trait?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/73449/quando-devo-usar-heran%C3%A7a-classe-abstrata-interface-ou-um-trait)