# Como utilizar Traits em PHP?

Tags: php, orientação-a-objetos, trait

Estou criando *namespaces* para minhas *traits* e usando elas diretamente, sem usá-las dentro de uma classe específica, exemplo:

**OBS: O código abaixo é só um exemplo.**

```
namespace Decrypt;

trait Rc4 {

    public function nome()
    {
        return "Fulano";
    }
}
```

Então eu chamo elas diretamente assim:

```
use Decrypt\Rc4;

echo Rc4::nome();
```

Posso usar as *traits* dessa maneira? Isso está correto?

Mesmo que eu não possa fazer isso, ou seja mesmo que um *trait* não possa existir sem uma classe, posso agrupá-los em um *namespace* para usar em classes diferentes, porém que compartilham de algumas funcionalidades iguais?

Comment: A primeira pergunta que deve fazer é porque está fazendo isto. Porque não usar o mecanismo correto? Se realmente tiver motivo para fazer isto, tentou, deu certo?

Comment: `Trait` é uma forma de estruturação para regras de negócio relacionadas e independentes. Por definição, uma `trait` não deve existir sem uma classe, pois a primeira define o comportamento da segunda, então acredito que não, você não deve fazer isso.

Comment: Entendi foi pro isso que criei as traits, porque algumas classes precisavam de novas funcionalidades e percebi que essas funcionalidades poderiam existir em outras classes que é o que realmente aconteceu, só que as vez usei elas independentemente das classes, então agora eu vou concertar isso.

Comment: Percebi também que não da para agrupa-las em um namespace se tivermos que da um use na trait dentro da classe.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Assim como o [@Anderson Carlos Woss](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/5878/anderson-carlos-woss) já comentou e praticamente já respondeu suas questões, farei um adendo conforme você pode ler na [documentação](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/language.oop5.traits.php):

O que são `Traits`?

> Traits são mecanismos para reuso de código em linguagens de herança única.

Elas devem ser usadas onde não há não relações e não podem/deveriam estender/herdar de outra classe. Utilizado o exemplo do [Thiago Belem](http://blog.thiagobelem.net/php-5-4-traits) , imagine uma funcionalidade de `log`, onde geralmente você criaria uma classe para manipular isso:

```
class Log {
    public function log($message) {
        // Salva $message em um log de alguma forma
    }
}
```

E para usá-la, você faria algo parecido com:

```
class Usuario extends Model {

    protected $Log;

    public function __construct() {
        $this->Log = new Log();
    }

    public function save() {
        // Salva o usuário de alguma forma
        // ...

        // Salva uma mensagem de log
        $this->Log->log('Usuário criado');
    }

}
```

Veja o trabalho que você precisa ter para utilizar essa funcionalidade, quando poderia simplificar utilizando `Traits`:

```
trait Log {

    public function log($message) {
        // Salva $message em um log de alguma forma
    }

}
```

Definindo o comportamento na classe:

```
class Usuario extends Model {

    use Log;

    public function save() {
        // Salva o usuário de alguma forma
        // ...

        // Salva uma mensagem de log
        $this->log('Usuário criado');
    }

}
```

**Respondendo as suas questões:**

> Posso usar as traits assim ?

Se a linguagem permite usar assim é uma coisa, se DEVE é outra totalmente distinta. E pra segunda opção, é **não**.

> isso esta correto ?

Não, não está correto. Na própria documentação diz que não é possível instância-la por conta própria.

Dê uma lida em [Horizontal Reuse](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/horizontalreuse) pra entender um pouco melhor o que se propõe com o uso de `Traits`.

Comment: ótima resposta, mereceu um +1. Uma única correção é que Traits [aceitam chamadas em caso de métodos estáticos](https://ideone.com/D2GRq2).

Answer (score 14):

[Tem uma pergunta aqui que fala sobre o básico do *trait*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/156913/101). E também [quando escolher usar cada estrutura](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/73449/101).

PHP realmente permite usar *trait* diretamente, mas isto é conceitualmente errado. É PHP sendo PHP. É sabido que a linguagem nunca se valeu de conceitos corretos. Então você pode usar, nada impede, mas se vai usar um recurso sofisticado é melhor usá-lo como ele foi pensado.

*Trait* serve para adicionar funcionalidades em uma classe, não serve para substituir classes.

Na verdade o exemplo usado é tão simples que se for fazer isso nem classe deveria existir. Eu sei que pode ser só um exemplo, mas neste, não é necessário. É comum as pessoas quererem encapsular funções dentro de classes para dizer que estão fazendo OOP. OOP nada tem a ver com colocar tudo em classes. E OOP por si só não garante código ser melhor, pelo contrário. Vou repetir uma frase aqui que o povo gostou: OOP é como sexo de adolescente, todo mundo fala que faz, mas fazer mesmo poucos fazem. Se quer fazer entenda bem o conceito, e quase ninguém entende, poucos ensinam certo, e aí saberá porque o *trait* é útil.

Só crie *trait* quando for a melhor ferramenta possível. Pode ser que uma interface seja a melhor opção, pode ser que uma classe abstrata seja a melhor opção, ou pode ser que nem isso precise. Não crie um para usar em zero classes, não crie para usar em uma classe.

Se já abusa da herança de classes provavelmente abusará da herança de *traits*. Percebo que em PHP é onde mais tem abuso de herança violando **por completo** o [princípio de Liskov](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/53468/101). Claro que o *trait* pode até ser uma salvação já que a intenção dele é adicionar uma funcionalidade, o que pode resolver a questão da herança equivocada. Mas considere que essa funcionalidade deva estar em uma classe totalmente separada, obedecendo o [princípio da responsabilidade única](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/100516/101).

A diferença básica da interface e *trait* é que a primeira fornece apenas um contrato, e o segundo também fornece uma implementação padrão para o contrato estabelecido ali.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/PHP/Conceptual.md).