# Diferença entre table, entity e behavior

Tags: php, cakephp-3

Qual é a diferença entre **table**, **entity** e **behavior** no contexto da Model?
Por exemplo, tenho uma tabela chamada módulo, quero fazer uma consulta como essa

```
$modulo = TableRegistry::get('Modulo');
    $resultado = $modulo ->find()
        ->select(['Modulo.Id_Modulo', 'Modulo.Nome_Modulo'])
        ->where(['Modulo.Id_Modulo => $idModulo])
        ->contain(['Acao']);
```

Em qual classe devo colocar esse trecho de código?

Answer (score 2):

> Qual é a diferença entre table, entity e behavior no contexto da Model?

Enquanto [`Table`](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/table-objects.html) é responsável por acessar e representar uma coleção de objetos, uma [Entity](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/entities.html) representa um objeto singular dessa coleção.

O [`behavior`](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/behaviors.html), assim como sua tradução literal diz, é um comportamento que pode ser estendido ao seu `Model`, atribuindo-lhe comportamentos comuns a outros models. É similar aos [`Traits`](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/219197/como-utilizar-traits-em-php/219204#219204).

> Em qual classe devo colocar esse trecho de código?

Conforme a própria [documentação](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/pt/orm.html) diz:

> No CakePHP seu modelo de domínio da aplicação é dividido em 2 tipos de
>   objetos principais. Os primeiros são repositories (repositórios) ou
>   table objects (objetos de tabela). Estes objetos fornecem acesso a
>   coleções de dados. Eles permitem a você salvar novos registros,
>   modificar/deletar os que já existem, definir relacionamentos, e
>   executar operações em massa. O segundo tipo de objetos são as entities
>   (entidades). Entities representam registros individuais e permitem a
>   você definir comportamento em nível de linha/registro e
>   funcionalidades.

Exemplificando:

```
namespace App\Model\Modulo;

use Cake\ORM\TableRegistry;

class ModuloTable extends Table
{
    public getAllModuloAcao($idModulo)
    {
        $modulo = TableRegistry::get('Modulo');
        return $modulo ->find()
        ->select(['Modulo.Id_Modulo', 'Modulo.Nome_Modulo'])
        ->where(['Modulo.Id_Modulo' => $idModulo])
        ->contain(['Acao']);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Tentando simplificar:

Table representa uma tabela.

Entity representa somente um registro. Tratamento de senha, que lida com um registro do usuário é feito na classe Entity.

Behavior é para o model o que o Component é para o Controller. O Behavior é completar do Model.