# Classes com operações estendendo outra classe

Tags: php, orientação-a-objetos, classes, herança

Tenho uma classe chamada `cliente`

```
class cliente {
    private $id;
    private $nome;

    function getId() {
        return $this->id;
    }

    function getNome() {
        return $this->nome;
    }
    function setId($id) {        
        $this->id = $id;       

    }

    function setNome($nome) {        
        $this->nome = $nome;
    }
}
```

E duas outras classes chamadas `selecionaCliente` e `insereCliente` essas duas estendem a classe `cliente`:

```
<?php
require_once 'cliente.php';
class insereCliente extends cliente{
    private $pdo;           
    function __construct() {
    require_once 'conbdd.php';        
    $db = new conbdd;
    $this->pdo = $db->conectar();        
    }
    function selId(){
        try{
            $sel=$this->pdo->prepare("SELECT name FROM clientes WHERE 
            id=:id");
            $sel->bindValue(":id", $this->getId());
            $sel->execute();
            $temp=$sel->fetch();
            $this->setNome($temp['nome']);
            return TRUE;        
        } catch (PDOException $ex){
            echo $ex->getMessage();
            return FALSE;

        }        
} 
<?php
require_once 'cliente.php';
class selecionaCliente extends cliente{
    private $pdo;           
    function __construct() {
    require_once 'conbdd.php';        
    $db = new conbdd;
    $this->pdo = $db->conectar();        
    }
    function insNome(){
    try {
        $ins= $this->pdo->prepare("UPDATE clientes SET nome=:nome WHERE 
        id=:id");
        $ins->bindValue(":id", $this->getId());
        $ins->bindValue(":nome", $this->getNome());
        $ins->execute();
        return TRUE;            
    } catch (PDOException $ex) {
        echo $ex->getMessage();
        return FALSE;
    }        
  }        
}
```

Quero validar e armazenar os dados do cliente dentro da classe `cliente` através da classe que vai utilizar as informações

Se eu instanciar as duas classes `selecionaCliente` e `insereCliente` e setar uma informação na `selecionaCliente` vou poder recuperar essa informação através da instancia da classe `insereCliente`, ou cada instancia cria um cliente diferente? Caso seja isto, como eu poderia fazer todas as classes usarem a mesma instancia de `cliente`?

Comment: `selecionaCliente` e `insereCliente` são nomes estranhos para classes. Parece que o problema é outro. Qual seria a responsabilidade de cada classe?

Comment: a classe cliente vai validar e armazenar as informaçoes do formulario a classe insereCliente vai fazer os insert no bdd e a selecionaCliente vai fazer os select no bdd e as duas devem pegar as informações ja validadas da classe cliente

Comment: @RodrigoMarques A resposta resolveu sua dúvida? Acha que pode aceitá-la? Veja o [tour] se não souber como faz. Isso ajudaria muito indicar que a solução foi útil para você. Também pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo (quando tiver 15 pontos, e terá assim que aceitar).

Answer (score 3):

A pergunta não tem muitos detalhes mas já dá para dizer que a premissa está errada.

Herança foi criada para estender algo naturalmente, o que está fazendo não é uma extensão, então a herança não cabe. Se não atende o [princípio de substituição de Liskov](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/53468/101) não faça herança. Poucas coisas merecem herança. Extensão deve adicionar algo a uma classes existente, não criar algo diferente e dar acesso direto à classe.

Se o modelo está errado qualquer mecanismo que use é inadequado.

Quase sempre a composição é o caminho mais adequado. Neste caso não sei nem se transformar esta suposta herança em composição é a solução. Nem parece ser caso de compor.

Na verdade é possível que esteja precisando de um [`trait`](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/219197/101) para o `Cliente`. Se há alguma composição é o cliente ter a capacidade de selecionar ou inserir o cliente. Mas acho que isto é algo mais avançado, provavelmente não conseguiria usar corretamente.

Se for seguir estritamente a orientação a objeto, e não estou dizendo que é a melhor solução, essas classes deveriam ser apenas métodos dentro de `Cliente`. Eu poderia até falar em interface, mas pelos nomes nem cabe isso.

Me parece que [não há coesão nestas classes, e elas são tão acopladas que deveriam ser uma coisa só](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/81314/101).

Se ainda seguir o caminho destas classes, o que eu não recomendo, provavelmente haveria um campo nelas que receberia o cliente a ser manipulado. No caso de `selecionaCliente` nem imagino como isto seria feito porque não parece haver relação com um cliente só, o que indica que toda ideia está errada.

É possível que estas "classes" deveriam ser métodos em uma classe auxiliar que manipula clientes. De qualquer forma vai pelo mais simples até aprender fazer o mais complexo.

Minha sugestão é entender o que vai usar antes de usar. Me parece que falta entendimento para que serve cada coisa na linguagem.

Com a edição da pergunta fica claro que deveriam ser apenas 2 métodos dentro da classe `Cliente` ou de uma classe `DAOCliente` (que receberia o cliente por parâmetro) e nenhuma herança deveria ocorrer. Nem vou questionar se deveria ser assim em PHP e dos outros problemas do código, já faço isso em vários *posts* aqui no site.

Não posso ajudar mais porque a pergunta não ajuda.

Comment: vou tentar explicar melhor:

Comment: o problema é que a classe cliente recebe mais informações como endereço telefone... e o netbeans esta reclamando que só pode ter 200 linhas então separei os insert e select mas a nova classe ficou grande também então estava separando os select dos insert e me ocorreu que cada classe vai chamar uma classe cliente diferente

Comment: Mande o NetBeans passear. Faça o certo e não se preocupe com ele. Eu desligaria essas "dicas" sem sentido.

Comment: tudo bem então,Obrigado

Comment: Quando for escrever código php, sugiro tentar seguir uma padronização, que pode ser [conferida aqui](https://www.php-fig.org). A herança só se faz necessária, quando ela foi feita para ser parte de dentro do processo de seu escopo (e geralmente tem uma relação meio que direta com ele), não faz sentido herdar uma entidade para um modelo de negócio. Eu poderia te transcrever uma solução mais simples para o caso, mas primeiro vc precisa entender como se deve usar uma entidade. Por exemplo, vc teria que criar uma classe "Gerente" para extender sua entidade "Cliente".

Comment: Dentro de Gerente, abstrair essas duas classes e criar apenas dois métodos: `inserir()`, `listar()`. No construtor você chama o banco...

Comment: Em vez de usar require, pode usar namespace; e com o composer instalar um autoload... para suas classes