# Qual é a diferença entre mixins e herança?

Tags: orientação-a-objetos, herança, mixin

Conceitualmente, há diferença entre uma classe que estende um módulo por *mixin* e uma classe que herde outra classe (herança única)?

Sei que por *mixins*, uma classe pode estender múltiplos módulos, o que não é permitido na maioria das linguagens de programação com herança.

Como o conceito de *mixin* varia muito de implementação para implementação, aqui defino aquele que considera-se uma classe (ou módulo) que [não possui construtores explícitos e nem estados, utilizado para estender comportamentos.](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/43023/41056)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Cada vez mais estou convencido que todos esses termos são um pouco frágeis. É comum significar coisas diferentes para pessoas/comunidades diferentes.

O que eu entendi até hoje é que a [herança faz subtipo e subclasse](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/152266/101). E meu entendimento sobre *mixins* é que ele só faz subclasse, portanto [há uma inclusão](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mixin) e não uma herança, ele mistura partes. Acho a ideia "errada" aí, é o "estende", não há extensão, há inclusão.

Em tese é mais fácil misturar várias partes porque o contrato do tipo não está presente, não há confusão. Não é que tenha zero confusão, é que a confusão não (deveria) fica(r) pública. O programador deve lidar com os conflitos que possa gerar, mas isso só influencia internamente.

Pense nele como uma classe abstrata ou um [*trait*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/156913/101) que não cria contratos naquele tipo. O objetivo dele é prover o detalhe da implementação, não a API. Se ele não pode ser instanciado, nem dá para comparar com uma classe concreta. Se tem uma implementação nem dá para comparar com interface. Se há estado nem dá para comparar com *trait*, Se não tem tipo nem dá para comprar com classe abstrata.

Algumas pessoas chamam de herança privada, e [C++ faz assim](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/private-inheritance) mesmo.

[D faz isso com *templates*](https://dlang.org/spec/template-mixin.html).

[É possível fazer um PHP](http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php), mas acho que nunca vi alguém fazendo. É muito comum os programadores dessa linguagem só seguirem receitas e não entendem os mecanismos que ela dispõe e como usá-los criativamente, o que pode ser bom se for para fazer errado.

[Scala diz ter](https://docs.scala-lang.org/tour/mixin-class-composition.html), mas tenho minhas dúvidas se é *mixin* mesmo. Não tenho base para afirmar.

[Python pode fazer](http://wiki.c2.com/?MixinsForPython) com os mecanismos existentes.

E claro, [Ruby também](http://rubylearning.com/satishtalim/modules_mixins.html), é bem popular nela.

Tenho a impressão que algumas linguagens estão chamando *traits* de *mixins*. Meu entendimento é que o *mixin* ocorre quando o código provê implementações necessárias para fazer alguma coisa que se pretende dentro daquele tipo.

Em linguagens dinâmicas pode ser que os conceitos se misturem. Em geral elas adotam uma postura chamada, talvez erroneamente, de [*duck typing*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/574146/101), então no momento que faz a subclasse o subtipo fica subentendido, e aí parece ser a definição de *trait*.

Embora, em tese, o *trait* não possa ter estado, e o *mixin* pode. Digo, em uma tese, porque tem outras pessoas que questionam isso.

Não sei se uma simples composição feita em forma específica não poderia ser considerado uma mistura.

Uma [explicação extensiva](https://github.com/SpongePowered/Mixin/wiki/Introduction-to-Mixins---Understanding-Mixin-Architecture).

[Mais informações](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/263306/101).

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Classes `partial` do C# são _mixin_?

Comment: Não considero, mas é uma forma de mixagem, se alguém disser que é, não vou discordar totalmente. è considerado abuso fazer uso deste mecanismo para tentar simular um *mixin*, ele não foi criado para isso e não é adequado.