# Implementações padrão em interface com C#

Tags: c#, orientação-a-objetos, interface

Estava lendo sobre as novas funcionalidades do C# 8 e me deparei com o *Default Interface Implentations*, ou seja, implementações padrão em interfaces.

O código abaixo exemplifica

```
public interface IBankAccountManager{ 
  void PerformTransaction(decimal amount, string reason); 
  void PerformDebit(decimal amount, string reason){ 
    PerformTransaction(-1 * amount, $"Debit: {reason}"); 
  } 

  void PerformCredit(decimal amount, string reason){ 
    PerformTransaction(amount, $"Credit: {reason}"); 
  } 
}
```

Como podemos ver, o método `PerformDebit` possui, além do contrato, uma implementação padrão, que executa o método `PerformTransaction`.

Estou pensando se isso não se opõe ao propósito básico de uma interface, que é estabelecer um contrato, e não uma implementação.

Esse tipo de situação é comum numa classe abstrata, que pode tanto ter implementações, quanto métodos abstratos, que devem ser sobrescritos (`override`).

O exemplo seria a implementação abaixo:

```
public abstract class BankAccountManager
{
    void PerformTransaction(decimal amount, string reason) { }
    void PerformDebit(decimal amount, string reason)
    {
        PerformTransaction(-1 * amount, $"Debit: { reason}");
    }

    void PerformCredit(decimal amount, string reason)
    {
        PerformTransaction(amount, $"Credit: {reason}");
    }
}
```

Voltando ao caso da interface, me parece que fugiu um pouco ao propósito de uma interface. Fui então pesquisar a literatura da OO sobre isso:

https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-BR/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/interfaces/

> Uma interface contém definições para um grupo de funcionalidades
>   relacionadas que uma classe ou um struct pode implementar.

E mais abaixo no *link*:

> A interface não fornece nenhuma funcionalidade que uma classe ou um
>   struct possa herdar da forma que ela pode herdar a funcionalidade da
>   classe base

Ou seja, no *link* a própria Microsoft se contradiz quanto a isso.

Outras referências:

[classe-abstrata-x-interface](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/3603/classe-abstrata-x-interface)

> Uma classe abstrata pode conter lógica (código), enquanto que uma
>   interface somente pode especificar quais os métodos ou propriedades
>   (no caso de .NET) uma classe que implementa a interface deve definir.

E temos a pergunta *"Em OOP, uma interface pode ter atributos?"* [em-oop-uma-interface-pode-ter-atributos](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/89894/em-oop-uma-interface-pode-ter-atributos)

Que tem as seguintes respostas:
1)

> Uma interface é uma "classe puramente abstrata", que somente
>   especifica um tipo mas não o concretiza.

2)

> Em geral, não. Mas nada impede que uma linguagem determine que pode.
>   Seria estranho, mas pode. Provavelmente ela deixaria de ser exatamente
>   uma interface, ainda que mantivesse o nome.

A segunda resposta do @Maniero faz sentido, pode parecer não estar correto, mas não há nada dizendo que nao pode ser feito. No [Wiki](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interface_(programa%C3%A7%C3%A3o_orientada_a_objetos)):

> Na programação orientada a objeto, a interface de um objeto consiste
>   de um conjunto de métodos que um objeto deve suportar.

Vi que no Java, a partir da versão 8, também [tem os *Default Methods*](https://dzone.com/articles/interface-default-methods-java), que é a mesma funcionalidade de implementar código na *interface*.

Ainda assim, duas dúvidas:

- Por que não usar uma classe abstrata no lugar de um *Default Method* para implementar código nos métodos?
- Qual cenário seria útil para implementar na interface e que não pode ser feito com uma classe abstrata?

Comment: No caso do Java, o [tutorial da Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/defaultmethods.html) e o artigo do dzone que você linkou explicam o principal caso de uso: estender as funcionalidades de uma interface sem quebrar a retrocompatibilidade. Já no caso do C#, não sei se foi criado pelo mesmo motivo, ou se funciona exatamente do mesmo jeito.

Comment: Bem pontuado @hkotsubo, é um motivo aceitável, no `C#` seria o mesmo cenário, mas me parece que versionar também resolveria o problema

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> > Uma interface contém definições para um grupo de funcionalidades relacionadas que uma classe ou um struct pode implementar.
>
> E mais abaixo no link:
>
> > A interface não fornece nenhuma funcionalidade que uma classe ou um struct possa herdar da forma que ela pode herdar a funcionalidade da classe base

Obviamente essa definição mudará. Isso é normal em revisões até mesmo da especificação da linguagem.

Tudo o que se dizia sobre interfaces de C# se torna obsoleto no C# 8. Como já ocorreu em Java. Por isso que eu falo para as pessoas tomarem cuidado com o que leem. Aquilo pode ter sido postado com a melhor das intenções, estar correto quando postado, ser de alguém que conhece o assunto, mas o tempo faz aquilo ser até mesmo errado, sem que ela saiba (ou lembre).

> > Em geral, não. Mas nada impede que uma linguagem determine que pode. Seria estranho, mas pode. Provavelmente ela deixaria de ser exatamente uma interface, ainda que mantivesse o nome.

De fato a interface passa ser um [*trait*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/279252/101), ou quase. É só uma questão de manter o nome pra não introduzir uma nova palavra-chave. Ele foi [criado pra isso](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/156913/101).

> > Na programação orientada a objeto, a interface de um objeto consiste de um conjunto de métodos que um objeto deve suportar.

A Wikipedia em português não é muito boa e por ser uma fonte que se espera canônica, deveria ser mais cuidadosa. É quase isso, mas não 100%. Tem muita lambança em vários artigos sobre OOP, mesmo em inglês, mas em português, é terrível.

> Por que não usar uma classe abstrata no lugar de um Default Method para implementar código nos métodos?

Só uma classe abstrata pode ser herdada. Interfaces podem muitas. Esse é o principal motivo para ter um mecanismo novo.

> Qual cenário seria útil para implementar na interface e que não pode ser feito com uma classe abstrata?

Este que acabei de citar. Também ajuda a dar uma semântica um pouco melhor da intenção.

O que vai abrir de útil, e que a classe abstrata já permitia, mas com a limitação de poder ser apenas uma herdada, é que pode adicionar um método novo no contrato e não quebrar a aplicação porque agora todos os tipos que implementam aquela interface não possuem implementação daquele método. A nova forma de usar interface permite que você forneça a implementação e aí todos tipos implementadores dela já ganham o comportamento "de graça", podendo sobrepô-lo, claro. Inclusive facilitará alguns padrões de projeto, como o Adapter, por exemplo.

Comment: *'A nova forma de usar interface permite que você forneça a implementação e aí todos tipos implementadores dela já ganham o comportamento "de graça"'*. Bom ponto, só precisamos ficar atentos para não fazermos mal uso isso. Nos exemplos que falamos, podemos implementar uma lógica pra chamar um método legado, para inclusive converter algum valor para manter a compatibilidade, etc. Entendo que isso ajuda muito, mas o problema é se colocar muita lógica no método e fugir do propósito

Comment: Claro, isso pode acontecer em qualquer lugar e depende do programador. Alguém pode por exemplo escrever 5mil linhas em um método, e não ser na interface. Como todo recurso tem que ser usado com atenção.

Comment: Exato, abusar e fazer errado sempre pôde, não é esse novo recurso que permitirá.

Answer (score -2):

Clássico:

```
public interface IAnimal
{
    double Peso { get; }
    double MaiorEstatura { get; }
    double Engorda(double ganhoDePeso);
    double Emagrece(double perdaDePeso);
    string EmissaoTipicaDeSom();
    bool EstaVivo { get; }
}
```

Animais não têm emissão de som em comum. Cada um emite um tipo de som. Além disso, o som varia de acordo com a ocasião.

Também existe o fato de que não podem engordar ou emagrecer indefinidamente, senão morrem.

Algum comportamento básico seria comum entre diferentes categorias de seres vivos, e isso poderia ser descrito (implementado) usando uma classe abstrata ou não. A vantagem de se usar uma classe abstrata é que esse comportamento comum não instanciaria, ou seja, não existiria como uma entidade viva.

Comment: Marcelo, entendi o exemplo em relação a implementar uma classe abstrata, mas não entendi a relação desse exemplo com as dúvidas do *default implementation*.

Comment: A _default implementation_ é só jogada da Microsoft para não ficar atrás ante as iniciativas do Android (Java) e do iOS (Swift et alli).