# Como resolver este problema de herança diamante

Tags: c#, herança, interface

Alguém pode solucionar este problema (herança diamante) com o uso de Interfaces e postar aqui em c#? Encontrei-o neste post: [Por que o C# não permite heranças multiplas?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/3596/por-que-o-c-n%C3%A3o-permite-heran%C3%A7as-multiplas) mas não consegui resolvê-lo.

Herdar de muitas classes concretas é uma grande fonte de problemas do ponto de vista do design de uma linguagem de programação: o que fazer se as duas superclasses tiverem um método do mesmo nome? E se tiver variáveis de instância do mesmo nome? Um problema particularmente complicado é a **herança diamante**. Considere o seguinte padrão de herança:

```
  A
 / \
B   C
 \ /
  D
```

A é uma superclasse que define um método virtual foo(). B e C são classes que herdam de A e reimplementam foo. Finalmente, D é uma classe que herda múltiplamente de B e C. Agora, se fizermos

```
A obj = new D();

obj.foo();
```

Qual versão do método é chamada? A versão definida em B ou a definida em C?

Devido a essas complicações, muitas linguagens de programação (incluindo C# e Java) preferem deixar as coisas mais simples e permitem apenas a herança simples.

Dito isso, pode ser que a linguagem forneça alternativas para alguns dos usos mais comuns de herança múltipla. Por exemplo, C# permite que uma classe implemente mais de uma Interface, que é similar a herdar multiplamente de classes puramente abstratas.

Comment: Poderiam por favor postar o post que tem a solução em c# deste problema que coloquei aqui? Os dois que negativaram não postaram. Eu não ligo para pontos, só quero que me orientem.

Comment: O problema não pode ser reproduzido, porque não é possível herdar duas classes... você poderia herdar duas interfaces, mas na interface não tem implementação... ps. Não negativei

Comment: Mas não há solução (atingir o mesmo objetivo) com o uso de interfaces?

Comment: Bom, vou pesquisar mais, eu sou muito afobado. Quando me deparo com uma dúvida já quero perguntar para alguém que manja do assunto.

Comment: não... na interface não tem implementação, não tem como sobrescrever... veja esses dois exemplos: https://dotnetfiddle.net/nqYjvO e https://dotnetfiddle.net/qlz4Wk

Comment: `c#` não herda duas classes, então isso não pode ser resolvido nessa linguagem. 
*"C# permite que uma classe implemente mais de uma Interface, que é similar a herdar multiplamente de classes puramente abstratas"*, sim é verdade, a diferença básica era que uma classe abstrata pode ter operações implementadas, comportamento, enquanto a interface não, até recentemente, quando as interfaces em .net agora permitem implementações, fiz até uma pergunta sobre isso: [implentacoes padrao com c#](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/305209/implementa%C3%A7%C3%B5es-padr%C3%A3o-em-interface-com-c)

Comment: @RovannLinhalis  *"na interface não tem implementação"*, agora tem com c#8  [implentacoes padrao com c#](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/305209/implementa%C3%A7%C3%B5es-padr%C3%A3o-em-interface-com-c)

Comment: @RicardoPontual, sim havia visto sua pergunta inclusive dei +1 lá... mas não tenho informação de qual seria o comportamento nessa situação, então preferi manter a referência das versões anteriores. Assim que eu tiver acesso ao C# 8, pretendo fazer esse teste

Comment: Só achei que essa nova funcionalidade meio que mata a classe abstrata. Tem que ver a fundo o que pode ser implementado, mas se não houver limitações, a diferença da classe abstrata passa a deixar de existir

Comment: Não faço ideia de qual é a dúvida aqui. Falou-se muito, com razão, tem uma interrogação que é retórica, tem outras que não são possíveis em C#. Pergunta não vi.

Comment: Lendo os comentários aqui já digo que não é bem assim :)

Comment: Minha dúvida é se há como fazer essa herança diamante com o uso de interfaces.

Answer (score 3):

Hoje, isso não é possível na linguagem, contudo, na versão 8 do C#, será possível ter a implementação default de métodos em interfaces, de qualquer forma, uma das interfaces deverá ser implementada de forma explícita.