# Qual é a diferença entre um decorator, atributo, aspecto e trait?

Tags: funções, terminologia, ciência-da-computação

Todos eles parecem servir para mudar a forma de executar uma função, mas imagino que existam diferenças entre eles.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Um **decorador** é uma função ou uma classe que pode ser usada para modificar o comportamento de uma outra função ou uma classe sem alterar o código fonte. Decoradores podem ser usados para adicionar funcionalidades, como *logging*, cache ou autenticação, à funções ou classes. Assim pode-se fazer algo a mais com aquilo sem ter que escrever todo um código em cada uso.

Ele é um [padrão de projeto](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/96452/101) cujo mecanismo pode variar em cada tecnologia, em alguns casos existe algo na linguagem que ajude, ou pode ser só uma forma de usar uma função ou classe que seja encapsulada pelo *decorator*.

Um **atributo** é um metadado que está associado a um objeto ou uma classe ou função, entre outras coisas. Ele pode ser pensado como uma variável que pertence a um objeto ou uma classe. Atributos podem ser usados para armazenar informações sobre um objeto ou uma classe e podem ser acessados ou modificados usando a [reflexão](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/506768/101).

Em alguns casos ele pode ser usado como parte do mecanismo de decorador para indicar qual é a decoração usada para que outra ferramenta faça a execução extra. No contexto seria isto, mas ele pode ser usado para outras decorações que não é o mesmo que o mecanismo anterior que adiciona comportamento a uma função. Ele em si não muda comportamento algum.

Um **aspecto** é uma preocupação transversal que afeta várias funções ou classes em um programa. Aspectos são usados para separar responsabilidades, como *logging*, tratamento de erros ou segurança (autorização), da lógica principal de um programa. Aspectos podem ser implementados usando decoradores ou outras técnicas. Geralmente é um mecanismo mais sofisticado que altera o código em momento posterior.

Geralmente a técnica é chamado de AOP (Aspect Oriented Programming). A maioria das tecnologias só conseguem ter isso com bibliotecas e outras ferramentas externas à linguagem.

Um ***trait*** é um conceito de programação que é usado para definir um conjunto de comportamentos comuns que podem ser compartilhados em várias classes ou objetos. *Traits* podem ser pensados como uma maneira de implementar herança múltipla sem alguns dos problemas que podem surgir da herança múltipla tradicional. Portanto, embora pareça que adiciona funcionalidade, não é da mesma forma. Em alguns casos que a linguagem não suporte, é possível simular com uma técnica de aspecto. [Veja mais](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/156913/101).

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Conceptual.md).